# Android docs is very slow in ADT r20

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I updated my ADT to r20. It becomes very slow to open the docs when I have internet connection. But it works well in offline mode.

It is very slow to open xxx.html in the docs directory by clicking them directly.

why? And how to fix it?

---

I found the problem. The url is something wrong when the html file accesses internet to download some resource files. I get these information when I access the docs' html file.

```
GET file://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,medium,thin,italic,mediumi‌​talic,bold 
GET file://www.google.com/jsapi/
```

The two are to download js files from internet, but fail to get them due to the wrong url.

How to prevent the two url accessing the internet? There are so many html files in docs, it is impossible to edit them all.

Help!